# Change or add section on checkout page opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.1.0.1, I need a custom payment module, so I created/duplicated the bank transfer method following [this](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=113&t=30653)

The module which I am making is for leasing plans about the products, so what I want is simply to show a small leasing table inside the payment section as shown on the picture.

[image]

I have the html/css code, but where should I implement it exactly? Also I will make it with radio buttons, so I want the admin to receive information which options were exactly selected by the buyer?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section is coming from `catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/payment/your-payment-name.tpl` file.

If you need HTML form, then it is better if you duplicate Paypal Pro method like in the tutorial instead of Bank Transfer.

Comment: I edited already the bank transfer method tpl file which i copyed, but yes, this answer would help me! Thanks